# .htaccess too many redirects on images

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have an htaccess file which I use to get some clean urls and to force www.
I added the code to redirect all http traffic to https the pages seem to work. But some images are not loading. I get "too many redirects" error.

```
# Redirect to www
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# ensure https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Redirect to apps
RewriteRule ^apps/([^/]*)$ apps.php?app=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^apps/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ apps.php?app=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

Comment: which uri causing the error?

Comment: @Ben uris leading to image files. They're giving too many redirects error

Comment: give example, please.

Comment: like if an image www.domain.com/images/inage.jpg

Comment: cannot see any problem related to htaccess. can you check if the problem still exist if use incognito mode, and did you post the full htaccess?